# Which champion can have the highest maximum health?

Tags: league-of-legends

Simple question with perhaps a difficult answer: which champion (in league of legends) can have the highest maximum health with a full build, and what would that build need to be to achieve this?

I would guess the champion would have to be [Alistar](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Alistar) with a base maximum health of 2278 at lv18

And if we stacked up with 6x [Warmog's Armor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warmog%27s_Armor), we would have 6*1000+2278 = 8278. But is there any way to go higher than that? Maybe with masteries and runes? What would the final maximum health be?

Comment: Including or excluding skills, or part of them like Sion's W, which allows for practically unlimited max health?

Comment: Ohh, sorry I forgot to mention that, excluding skills.

Comment: Spirit of the Ancient Golem gives +25% additional max health, so Id assume you'd probably want to get that

Comment: If my calculations are correct, that's only going to help over a Warmog's Armor, if I already have 5x warmogs and then buy the Spirit of the Ancient Golem: 5000*1.25=6250, 4000*1.5=6000, but it also gives +200 health so if I only used those, that would yield (2278 + 200 * 6) * (1 + 0.25 * 6) = 8695 a bit higher than 8278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both builds are definitly not viable for rankeds! Play them at own risk.

I'm not 100% sure if a i calculated the Health of Alistar corrently. I added all the flat bonus values (6007,76) and multiplied this with all percentages together (28%) and added the Base Health (2278):
(6007,76 * 128 / 100) + 2278.

If there is a misstake, feel free to edit this answer but provide the calculation formula.

### Alistar (without any skills involved)

the most health any champion can obtain is **9967,9328**, being a level 18 Alistar with:

**Base**:

- HP@18: 2278

**Runepage**:

- Full HP@18: 536,76

**Masteries**:

- Veteran's Scars: 36
- Juggernaut: 3%

**Items**:

- 5*Warmog's Armor: 5000
- 1*Spirit of the Ancient Golem: 200 and + 25% Bonus Health
- Elixir of Fortitude: 235

### [Sion (with skills involved)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sion#Soul_Furnace)

**unlimited health with Soul Furnace**

### [Nunu (with skills involved)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health#Trivia)

the most health any champion can obtain is **13195.95**, being a level 18 Nunu with:

All health runes and masteries:

- 9 Scaling Marks of Health (+87,48HP)
- 9 Scaling Glyphs of Health (+87,48HP)
- 9 Percent Seals of Health (+216HP)
- 3 Percent Quintessences of Health (+145,8HP)
- 3 points in Veteran's Scars mastery (+36HP)
- 1 point in Juggernaut mastery (+3%)
- 5 Warmog's Armor (+5000HP)
- 1 Spirit of the Ancient Golem (+200HP +25%)
- An Elixir of Fortitude (+235HP)
- Wild Growth cast by a Lulu with the maximum amount of ability power. (+???HP)
- Consume cast on a Golem jungle creep (+10%)

Comment: With skills included Sion gets unlimited health. Also I'm wondering about Vladimir who gains 120% of AP as health and Singed who gains 25% of mana as health.

Comment: Vladimir would need ~833 AP to compensate one Warmogs. Singed needs 4000 Mana  to compensate one Warmogs. There are no Items that can do that.

Comment: Yep but Vlad would still bring a ton more utility than an Alistar with this build ;)

Comment: uhm yeah..... but..... no... plz don't...

Comment: Time to make a new mobafire guide...

Comment: True, however Rod of Ages gives 650 health, 650 mana and 80 AP. Vlad gains ~750 hp, Singed gains ~830hp... It's not a Warmogs yet but I just wondered if there might be some way to get more out of them or some items I've missed.

Comment: Awesome answer! Also the scope of this question does not touch other thing such as utility or attack, so I would say, this answers everything that I asked. Thank you!

Comment: @19greg96 glad to hear that :) but i hope will never build full HP ali when you're in my team :D